# Are all people of Scripture unjust for not believing in the Quran according to [29:46]

Tags: quran, tafseer

Sahih International translation of [29:46]:

> And do not argue with the People of the Scripture except in a way that is best, **except for those who commit injustice among them**, and say, "We believe in that which has been revealed to us and revealed to you. And our God and your God is one; and we are Muslims [in submission] to Him."

Word used here is ظَلَمُوا۟.
Another word with same root is used in another place in a way similar to *"those who sin have commited injustice to themselves"*.

Therefore not believing in Qur'an is unjust meaning there can be no just person of book/scripture.

**Is the injustice in 29:46 a specific form? is there any tafseer on this?**

Remember that prefix "al-" is not used in 29:46. The prefix "al-" means "The" for example "al-Malik"  means "The King" .

Comment: I have another question but about the place where Quran says a thing like "no change to creation of Allah (you should make)". How do we know it only refers to animals? is there any hadith?

Comment: Would be better to ask that in a separate question.

Comment: ظَلَمُوا۟ is a verbal form. I don't see anything special in it and I would not expect an article. Is your question about the meaning of the verse?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that disbelieving the Quran is itself an act of injustice / wrongdoing.

> ومن أظلم ممن افترى على الله كذبا أو كذب بآياته إنه لا يفلح الظالمون
>
> And who is more unjust than one who invents about Allah a lie or denies His verses? Indeed, the wrongdoers will not succeed.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 6:21](http://quran.com/6/21)</sup>

There are three major interpretations of verse 29:46:

- 'People of the Scripture' here means those who have accepted Islam and believed in the Quran. Such as Abdullah ibn Salam, Salman al-Farsi, Adi ibn Hatim etc. Similar to how it is used in the verse:

  > وإن من **أهل الكتاب** لمن يؤمن بالله وما أنزل إليكم وما أنزل إليهم خاشعين لله لا يشترون بآيات الله ثمنا قليلا أولئك لهم أجرهم عند ربهم إن الله سريع الحساب
  >
  > And indeed, among the **People of the Scripture** are those who **believe** in Allah and **what was revealed to you** and what was revealed to them, [being] humbly submissive to Allah . They do not exchange the verses of Allah for a small price. Those will have their reward with their Lord. Indeed, Allah is swift in account.
  >
  > <sup>— [Quran 3:199](https://quran.com/3/199)</sup>

  Hence it is possible for a person to be from the 'People of Scripture' and to not commit any injustice, including kufr. So the verse is to be interpreted as follows:

  > do not argue with the People of the Scripture (i.e. the Muslims among them) ... except for those who commit injustice among them (i.e. the non-Muslims among them)
- 'Injustice' here means being a Harbi. If the 'people of the scripture' mentioned here are the disbelievers then it is implicitly understood that this verse means injustices other than kufr.

  > do not argue with the People of the Scripture (i.e. the Dhimmis) ... except for those who commit injustice (apart from disbelief) among them (e.g. the Harbis)
- This verse is abrogated by [9:29](https://quran.com/9/29?translations=20).

Ref:  [Tafsir al-Qurtubi](https://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/qortobi/sura29-aya46.html#qortobi) ,  [Tafsir al-Tabary](https://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/tabary/sura29-aya46.html#tabary)

Comment: 9:29 seems like misinterpreted. Qur'an has both metaphorical and literal statements. One should think and interpret Qur'an under the light of Qur'an and hadith. One can't interpret Qur'an however he wants